# \LaTeX logo too compressed with microtype and defined \SetExtraKerning

Tags: spacing, microtype, kerning, logos

I have, perhaps, a slightly odd problem. I have used `microtype` to define some special spacing rules. This is the relevant bit of the preamble (and I will have hopefully not forgotten anything --- if I have, please forgive).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,headheight=72pt,bottom=3cm,right=2.5cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,array,color,epigraph,floatflt,graphicx,marvosym,multirow,subcaption,siunitx,tabu,titlesec,tocbibind,tocloft}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\DeclareMathVersion{mathchartertext}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mathchartertext}{OML}{mdbch}{m}{n}

\SetExtraKerning[unit=space]
{encoding={*}, family={bch}, series={*}, size={footnotesize,small,normalsize}}
{\textendash={400,400}, % en-dash, add more space around it
 "28={ ,150}, % left bracket, add space from right
 "29={150, }, % right bracket, add space from left
 \textquotedblleft={ ,150}, % left quotation mark, space from right
 \textquotedblright={150, }
 } % right quotation mark, space from left

\SetExtraKerning[unit=space]
{encoding={*}, family={qhv}, series={b}, size={large,Large}}
{1={-200,-200}, \textendash={400,400}}

\SetTracking{encoding={*}, shape=sc}{40}
\begin{document}
This is a bad \LaTeX
\end{document}
```

Now, everything looks fine -- that is, everything except the LaTeX command itself (which was a pain to reference in the keywords section here by the way -- I thought of a not-very-good workaround, but what would have been the proper way?).

This is how it looks: [image: Example of how it looks]

As you can see, the entire bit in that command is far too compressed than what it should be. I figure that \SetExtraKerning can do the job, but I am not entirely certain what's the responsible way of going about it since I need to enter the space in the command/between the characters in the command.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Regards

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Does wrapping it in a box help? `\mbox{\LaTeX}`

Comment: @Jubobs : I wish I had thought of that. I have made the changes (although I hope you notice I did have a documentclass).

Comment: @SeanAllred : I am afraid not. I didn't think of it earlier, but I took a look now and it doesn't make a difference to the output.

Comment: You can quite easily modify the logo's appearance with the package `metalogo`.

Comment: Mmm perhaps you can do it manually once using the native `TeX` commands for it: `L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\\hbox{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125ex X}` Now you can fit manually the values for kerning until get it right. I do not recommend to do this more than once. If you have a loto of places to fit, you should use the `metalogo`package as @egreg suggested.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, the package sorts it nicely! If you add that as an answer, I can make the question "solved".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `metalogo` can help; you can easily define the kerning between pairs of letter; for example

```
\setlogokern{La}{-.18em}
```

will make the kerning between the ‘L’ and the ‘superscript A’ to half the default value.

The author has also written `mathspec` and the package was born from the need of adjusting the logos to different fonts.